# android x86 6.0 doesn't support mouse integration?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, android-x86, mouse

A while back, I made a virtual machine on VirtualBox for Android 4.4. I had a little trouble getting mouse integration to work for it, but I figured it out.

More recently, I tried Android 6.0 Marshmallow on a virtual machine. Mouse integration would not work, and as such, I could not get as far as setup. I've since moved back to Android 4.4 which displays a mouse pointer just fine.

Does android-x86 6.0 not support mouse integration?

Answer (score 1):

The solution from [Android X86 – No Mouse Cursor in Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.driscocity.com/android-x86-no-mouse-cursor-oracle-virtualbox/):

> 1. Make sure the VM is not running (powered off)
> 2. Click on the VM name in the list (e.g., Android X86)
> 3. Click Settings
> 4. Click on the System category
> 5. Make sure you’re on the Motherboard tab
> 6. Change Pointing Device to PS/2 Mouse